# How to find minimum distance path between 2 points on a surface

Tags: calculus, integration, optimization

Given a surface equation is $z=f(x,y)$  and also given two points on surface are $A(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $B(x_2,y_2,z_2)$

How can be found the path equation $(x=p(t),y=s(t),z=u(t))$ that it creates minimum distance between A and B on the surface $z=f(x,y)$ ?

we can write that
if $z=ax+by+c$  (plane) then the path equation must be a line between two points. (Proof done by using Euler-Lagrange Equation, the link is below)

And also as a sense  (without proof)
If  $z=\sqrt{r^2-x^2-y^2}$ (sphere) then the path equation must be the circle that its center is on origin.

My attempt to solve it:

$$d=\int^{t_1}_{t_2} \sqrt{dx^2+dy^2+dz^2}  $$
$$d=\int^{t_1}_{t_2} \sqrt{\frac{dx^2}{dt^2}+\frac{dy^2}{dt^2}+\frac{dz^2}{dt^2}} dt  $$

$$d=\int^{t_1}_{t_2} \sqrt{p'(t)^2+s'(t)^2+u'(t)^2} dt  $$

And also we know that 
$z=f(x,y)$

thus

$$u(t)=f(p(t),s(t))$$

I need minimum $d$ but I don't know how to proceed after that

I think I must use Euler-Lagrange Equation  but I could not establish the equation for 3D. There is solution in [here](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/336L/Fluidhtml/node181.html) for plane surface.

Thanks for answers and advice

EDIT: (June 3)

I used same strategy in link that I gave above and I got an equation.

$$F(p'(t),s'(t),u'(t))=\sqrt{p'(t)^2+s'(t)^2+u'(t)^2}$$

For stortest path:

$$0=\int^{t_1}_{t_2} \frac{d}{dt}(\frac{dF}{dp'}+\frac{dF}{ds'}+\frac{dF}{du'}) dt  $$

$$\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{dF}{dp'}+\frac{dF}{ds'}+\frac{dF}{du'})=0$$

$$\frac{dF}{dp'}+\frac{dF}{ds'}+\frac{dF}{du'}=k$$

Thus I got an equation for shortest path :

$$\frac{p'(t)+s'(t)+u'(t)}{\sqrt{p'(t)^2+s'(t)^2+u'(t)^2}}=k$$
where k is constant

It seems that  the equation confirms for plane case but I am not sure for other examples.

Is it correct equation?

Comment: Try using the fundamental theorem of Calculus to remove the integral sign: $$\frac{d}{dt} \int_{t_2}^{t_1} \sqrt{p'(t)^2+q'(t)^2+r'(t)^2} dt$$
$$\sqrt{p'(t_1)^2+q'(t_1)^2+r'(t_1)^2}-\sqrt{p'(t_2)^2+q'(t_2)^2+r'(t_2)^2}$$
This can be set equal to zero to find the minima and maxima.

Comment: We cannot use it here. Because $t_1$ and $t_2$ fixed points. Please check the link I gave.

Comment: It seems that you are searching a geodesic: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic.

Comment: Good catch. You are right about that.

Comment: You can try Dijkstras algorithm in computer science together with some grid approach, possibly multigrid.

Comment: Or you can do the brute force way and set the first point on the surface to be a source, the second to be a sink, define a tensor field cost for vectors normal to the surface and then minimizing the gradient of a vector field given those constraints. Can be done with Global Linear Optimization and if needed MRA / multi-scale or multi-grid if the surface is smooth enough.

Comment: @mathreadler Thanks a lot for  your comment. I try to find out theoretical solution for exact shortest path equation via calculus. I know we can do many things via computer algorithms but I am not interested in that way.

Comment: Finding analytical expressions for solutions to practically interesting problems is very difficult. I wish you all the luck, Mathlover.